# leftOuterJoin JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> and JavaPairRDD<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to perform leftOuterJoin of JavaPairRDD and JavaPairRDD> and in function signature return type is

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Map<Integer, Integer>>>>
```

Optional here is *com.google.common.base.Optional*

Is this the correct return type when I perform leftOuterJoin?

My IDE is giving this error

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) W exist so that Optinal<W> conforms to Optional<Map<Integer, Integer>>
```

I couldn't find proper documentation for this. If there are any links to understand this better that would be helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the javadoc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html), a left outer join between a RDD of type `JavaPairRDD<K, V>` and a RDD of type `JavaPairRDD<K,W>` will give you this: `JavaPairRDD<K,Tuple2<V,Optional<W>>>`.

This is what you wrote except that the Optional type is defined in spark's java API: `org.apache.spark.api.java.Optional<T>`. It is not the one defined by Google, hence the error your IDE throws at you ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Here http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html Signature was written as public <W> JavaPairRDD<K,scala.Tuple2<V,com.google.common.base.Optional<W>>> leftOuterJoin(JavaPairRDD<K,W> other) so I got confused.

Comment: This is the signature in spark 1.x but they changed it in 2.0.